# Java URL problem?

Tags: java, url, sockets, stream

Greetings all,

I am trying to download 'gz' file using URL class .Code snippet is as:

```
URL url = new URL("ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/structures/all/pdb/pdb132l.ent.gz");
InputStream conn = new GZIPInputStream(url.openStream());
```

But it throws the error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   ftp.wwpdb.org     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
>     at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
>     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:525)
>     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:475)

What could be the issue?

Comment: it works fine for me. which Java version are you using?

Comment: I download the file using Browser.But not in java?

Comment: I use java version "1.6.0_15" 64 bit (build 1.6.0_15-b03)

Comment: I am sorry, I was using 16bit JRE eventhough I'm in 64bit linux..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copy-pasted your code and it downloads the file on my machine. You probably have a network problem.

Comment: what? hmm..I can download the file using browser? only this happens in Java ?

Comment: and are you java network settings the same as the browser settings?

Comment: Can you try this: InetAddress.getLocalHost() and tell if you get UnknownHostException.

Comment: hi Peter, no there no errors for InetAddress.getLocalHost()

it gives "umanga/192.168.2.33"

Comment: I know this sounds crazy, but if you are using TCP/IPv6, could you try removing the support for it from your machine and try again.

Comment: I am sorry, I was using 16bit JRE in Eclipse. eventhough I'm in 64bit linux.I changed to 64bit and now everything is fine..thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the FTP username/password 
You can use some FTP client library to download from FTP.
http://www.ajaxapp.com/2009/02/21/a-simple-java-ftp-connection-file-download-and-upload/

Comment: hmm.you can directily download the file in browser
the link
 ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/structures/all/pdb/pdb132l.ent.gz